# How to querySelectorAll data attributes starting with the same characters

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have these attributes in my html file `<input type="number" data-input-primary-people />` and `<input type="number" data-input-primary-amount />` how to select these starting with `data-input-primary-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread operator and filter like this:

```js
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll("*")].filter(t => [...t.attributes].filter(({ name}) => name.startsWith("data-input-primary-")).length > 0)
        console.log(res);
```

```html
<input type="number" data-input-primary-people" />
<input type="number" data-input-primary-amount" />
<input type="number" data-input-primary1-amount" />
```

Comment: `data-input-primary-amount` is the attribute **name** (and `data` by itself isn't a valid name for an attribute in HTML except on `<object>` elements)